# How can I open csv file in powershell and remove lines with blank data, change column order and write out results

Tags: powershell, csv

I would like to open a csv file, check the contents of the row for missing data, exclude that row if data is missing, and then write out the columns in a different order than from what I read.

for example, here is the input CSV file:

```
"givenName","sn","userPrincipalName","telephoneNumber"
,,"Administrator@engeo.com",
"Citrix","Scheduler Service","citrixscheduler@engeo.com",
,,,
,,,
"dbagent",,"dbagent@engeo.com",
"Cory","Montini","cmontini@engeo.com","925-395-2566"
```

Here is what I would like the end result to be:

```
"userPrincipalName","sn","givenName","telephoneNumber"
"cmontini@engeo.com","Montini","Cory","925-395-2566"
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
$Path = 'c:\temp\ps\Test.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $Path | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.givenName -eq '' ) {
    # how do I remove the line
    }
    If ($_.ns -eq '' ) {
    # how do I remove the line
    }
    If ($_.userPrincipalName -eq '' ) {
    # how do I remove the line
    }
    If ($_.telephoneNumber -eq '' ) {
    # how do I remove the line
    }
    $_
} | Format-Table -AutoSize


(Import-CSV -Path $Path) | Select-Object -Property userPrincipalName, givenName, sn, telephoneNumber | Export-CSV -Path $Path
```

**my current output**

Is reordering the columns... but not removing data and I don't know why #TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject is on the first line

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"userPrincipalName","givenName","sn","telephoneNumber"
"Administrator@engeo.com","","",""
"citrixscheduler@engeo.com","Citrix","Scheduler Service",""
"","","",""
"","","",""
"dbagent@engeo.com","dbagent","",""
"cmontini@engeo.com","Cory","Montini","925-395-2566"
```

**UPDATE 1**

I changed the code to this

```
$Path = 'c:\temp\ps\Test.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $Path | Where-Object {
        $_.userPrincipalName -and $_.givenName -and $_.sn -and $_.telephoneNumber
    } | ForEach-Object {
    $_
} | Format-Table -AutoSize

(Import-CSV -Path $Path) | Select-Object -Property userPrincipalName, givenName, sn, telephoneNumber | Export-CSV -Path $Path
```

now I am getting the correct output in Powershell:

```
givenName sn      userPrincipalName  telephoneNumber
--------- --      -----------------  ---------------
Cory      Montini cmontini@engeo.com 925-395-2566
```

but my output file is still jacked up

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the latest code:

```
$Path = 'c:\temp\ps\Test.csv'
$Temp = 'c:\temp\ps\_temp.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $Path | Where-Object {
        $_.userPrincipalName -and $_.givenName -and $_.sn -and $_.telephoneNumber
    } | ForEach-Object {
    $_
} | Export-Csv -Path $Temp -NoTypeInformation

Remove-Item -Path $Path
Rename-Item -Path $Temp -NewName $Path

(Import-CSV -Path $Path) | Select-Object -Property userPrincipalName, givenName, sn, telephoneNumber | Export-CSV -Path $Path
```

I am getting closer... Here is the output, but where did the first line come from?

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"userPrincipalName","givenName","sn","telephoneNumber"
"cmontini@engeo.com","Cory","Montini","925-395-2566"
```

Comment: add the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet to remove the `#TYPE` line, also make sure not to add the `Format-Table` before the `Export-CSV`

Comment: thanks !  that helped !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
$InputFile = 'c:\temp\ps\Test.csv'
$Cleaned = 'c:\temp\ps\_cleaned.csv'
$Output = 'c:\temp\ps\_columnsAdjusted.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $InputFile | Where-Object {
        $_.userPrincipalName -and $_.givenName -and $_.sn -and $_.telephoneNumber
    } | ForEach-Object {
    $_
} | Export-Csv -Path $Cleaned -NoTypeInformation

(Import-CSV -Path $Cleaned) | Select-Object -Property userPrincipalName, givenName, telephoneNumber, sn | Export-CSV -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation

# this is clean up of temporary files and putting data into original file
Remove-Item -Path $Cleaned
Remove-Item -Path $InputFile
Rename-Item -Path $Output -NewName $InputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways, but quick and simple one can be:

```
$csv = Import-Csv [...] # add your csv path
$csv | ? {$_.givenName -ne '' -and $_.sn -ne '' `
-and $_.telephoneNumber -ne '' `
-and $_.userPrincipalName -ne ''} | 
Select userPrincipalName,sn,givenName,telephoneNumber
| Export-CSV -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

The output:

```
userPrincipalName  sn      givenName telephoneNumber
-----------------  --      --------- ---------------
cmontini@engeo.com Montini Cory      925-395-2566
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most obvious solution, but it is concise and works with any number of input columns:

```sh
(Import-Csv $Path) |
  Where-Object { $_.psobject.Properties.Value -notcontains '' } |
    Select-Object -Property userPrincipalName, givenName, sn, telephoneNumber |
      Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $Path
```

- The property values of custom objects constructed by `Import-Csv` from CSV input data are always *strings* (`[string]` instances).
- `$_.psobject.Properties.Value` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to return an array of all property (column) values.

  - `-notcontains ''` returns `$true` only for those input objects for which *all* properties (columns) are nonempty.

Note: As in your own attempt, the `(...)` around the `Import-Csv` command ensures that the input file is read *in full, up front*, which allows writing back to the same input file with `Export-Csv` in the same pipeline (note that there is a small risk of data loss, should the pipeline get interrupted).